# Can't read message in Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs-messages

Received a message from a recruiter but when I try to look at it in Google Chrome on my Android 10 this is what I get

[image]

I tried opening in Chrome's Desktop mode but the problem remained.

Comment: I can repro this on windows in Chrome -- messages tab is completely empty

Comment: Again? [Job messages not displayed](/q/411493/4642212)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for posting this bug!

We're doing some JS refactoring at the moment, and the Messages pages (which is different from all the other pages) often causes bugs because it gets overlooked when we're testing things. In particular, today's bug was because the Messages page was including some JS that was intended for the Talent side.

Should be fixed now, please let us know if you run into any other issues.

Comment: It's working now, thank you!